# Android - how to turn off screen for few hours and then turn it on again?

Tags: android, react-native

I have an Android TV box (Android 9) and a connected screen via HDMI. What I want to do is to programatically turn off the screen and then (after few hours) wake up the screen again.

I use [`react-native-idle-timer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-idle-timer) to turn off the screen (it just sets or removes `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`).

This works perfectly to turn off the screen (the `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` is removed from the activity and then the screen goes to sleep in few minutes).

**The issue is waking up the screen**.

It looks like that if the device is "sleeping" more than X minutes, it is not possible to wake it up anymore (probably because the app is somehow suspended / cpu stops?). To wake up the app, I use [`react-native-android-wake-screen`](https://github.com/witPranav/react-native-android-wake-screen/blob/main/android/src/main/java/com/reactlibrary/AndroidWakeScreenModule.java), which uses this to wake up the screen:

```java
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "yourApp:tag");
            wakeLock.acquire();
```

and I have this in the app's manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Do you have any idea how to make this work?

I have few ideas but not sure if they are suitable:

- somehow tell the system to never "suspend" the app (maybe setting [`PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) for the time the device should be sleeping?)
- set up an alarm that would wake up the device at specified time (and wake up the screen)

Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't know about React Native, but in native Android an [alarm](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms) would be the way to go.

Comment: Do u have an example how to do that? I would start an alarm with an intent that would then create a wakeLock and acquire it?

Comment: I don't have an example, sorry. Maybe someone else does.